# How do I count how many times a value has changed pertaining to a unique ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how many times a student has changed majors over the course of their college career.

```
   Create Table Taco
  (  s_id  varchar(9),
     s_year  int,
     s_major varchar(50))

 Insert INTO Taco 
 Values (123456789, 2018, 'PSYCHOLOGY'),
        (123456789, 2016, 'GENERAL EDUCATION'),
        (123456789, 2017, 'PSYCHOLOGY'),
        (987654321, 2018, 'FILM'),
        (987654321, 2017, 'ANTHROPOLOGY'),
        (654789123, 2018, 'BIOLOGY'),
        (654789123, 2017, 'BIOLOGY'),
        (987654321, 2015, 'COMPUTER SCIENCE')
```

I am expecting the result:

```
 s_id     changes
 123456789     2      
 987654321     3
 654789123     1
```

How would I write this?

Comment: why is s_id a varchar? Also, that table wouldn't hold that data since varchar default is 8 when the length isn't specified. Same thing for s_major

Comment: @scsimon actually the default length for a column is the same as a variable, 1. But for a parameter it is 30. Enough you make you go crazy for sure. The sentiment intended here is to ALWAYS specify a length for varchar.

Comment: @SeanLange my bad I meant to say 1 (was thinking 8 bytes char vs varchar), and 30 is for casting too right?

Comment: Yeah I think that is right. Damn difficult to remember which is why we all say to just be explicit and be certain. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the number of real changes you can use `LAG` function to receive the last value within a group (`s_id`) and sum up all differences between the previous value and the current value:

```sql
SELECT t.s_id
     , SUM(CASE WHEN t.prev_val <> t.s_major OR t.prev_val IS NULL THEN 1 END) as chg_cnt
FROM
   (
       SELECT s_id
             ,s_year
            , s_major
            , LAG(s_major) OVER(PARTITION BY s_id ORDER BY s_year) prev_val
       FROM Taco
    ) as t
GROUP BY s_id
```

extended sqlfiddle code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/61048/11

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm and just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Count` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT s_id,count(s_id) 'changes'
FROM Taco 
group by s_id
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2c1d7/2

Comment: Not at all saying this is incorrect because it is unclear if the same value can show up multiple times. And if it does should it count twice or once? This counts the number of rows but not necessarily the number of different majors. Would require clarity from the OP.

Comment: I have edited my values and I actually only want the same value to count once

Answer (score 0):

You can just count the entries in your table and substract one to determine the amount of changes for each student.

```
SELECT
  s_id,
  COUNT(s_id) - 1 AS [Amount of changes]
FROM
  Taco 
GROUP BY
  s_id
```

I would also recommend changing the type of the last column to `varchar(50)` or something bigger.

See SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/59ae2/1